# auto scroll when Mouse Over webbrowser control ( not Focus )

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

i create c# winform application contain 2 control : webbrowser and listbox (as pictured below).

How to auto scroll when mouse over control with mouse wheel event (webbrowser  without having to click on this control (or set focus to this control because i want to scroll webbrowser while mouse still focus on textbox)

[image]

Comment: Please post code showing what you have attempted to do. StackOverflow is not a give you the code website. Please show effort and follow these suggestions when asking questions: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: This is not how Windows works by default. If the user wants this behavior, they can set up their computer to behave this way. If they don't want it, then your application should not force it on them. Follow the standard platform idioms. You are not on Mac OS X.

Comment: @CodyGray - This _is_, increasingly, how Windows works by default; many applications work this way, and [Microsoft's own UX guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn742466%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#MOUSE_WHEEL) recommends it.

Comment: Skype work this way too

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to set the focus to the control when the mouse enters it:

```
private void Control_MouseEnter(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    var ctrl = sender as Control;
    if (ctrl == null) { return; }

    ctrl.Focus();
}
```

There are other more complex solutions like capturing the mouse events at the `Form` and then issuing the scroll on the corresponding control if the mouse is over them, but that requires point translation and a lot more code to handle the scroll method.  Doing it this way means the scroll wheel will take care of itself.

Comment: That's not what I need . 
because if set focus() to webbrowser control. textbox ( view my picture on post #1 ) will lost focus -> can't enter text.
I wan't scroll webbrowser control when mouse still focus on textbox ( but mouse over on webbrowser control )

Comment: Your answer would be better if it mentioned *why* this is problematic. Basically that, in Windows, keyboard/mouse events are received *only* by the focused window. Indeed, redirecting the scroll event from the focused control to the desired control is the first thing that came to my mind, but it's going to end up broken in subtle ways. It isn't worth the maintenance cost, especially since it breaks standard operating system behavior that users are well accustomed to.